# How to run angular 2 build files on express.js

Tags: angular, express

I want to run index.html and i get it from angular2 app after ng build.

I tried these two lines of code one by one but these are not working for me 
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname+'/public/index.html')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname+'/public')));

Any idea how to resolve this?

Your help will greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks for contributing a question! Try providing a little more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you already have the correct path to your `public` folder and also the `ng build` builds out to the `public` folder with the same path.

Do: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work with your code but i get the clue from your answer. i used the code below and its working now
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'public')));